# auto-complete mode performance is awful in nxml-mode

Tags: auto-complete-mode, performance

Performance used to be OK, but a couple of weeks ago the performance got much worse. Some experimentation showed that it's `auto-complete-mode` in XML files.

When I type, it now takes a second or two for each character to appear.

This is a profiler report that covers me typing three or four words:

```
+ timer-event-handler                                            1636  90%
+ ...                                                             115   6%
+ command-execute                                                  34   1%
+ ac-handle-post-command                                           25   1%
+ redisplay_internal (C function)                                   2   0%
+ key-chord-input-method                                            1   0%
```

I have no idea what to do with it though.

If I turn off `auto-complete-mode` the problem instantly goes away.

Ideas, anybody?

Thanks.

Comment: What are the timer events calling? They are likely auto-complete gathering candidates which may have a pathological interaction with nxml-mode.

Comment: how do i find out what they are calling? there seems to be no expansion of anything... this is the first time i have ever seen the profiler... be gentle...

Comment: I would look at the variable `ac-sources`. You could remove each source one by one (or bisect it) until you find the culprit.

Comment: @jack: hit return on line to expand it.

Answer (score 1):

When I expand the entries that are using the most CPU I get:

```
- timer-event-handler                                            3805  89%
 - byte-code                                                     3805  89%
  - apply                                                        3805  89%
   - ac-update-greedy                                            2717  64%
    - ac-update                                                  2713  64%
     - ac-menu-create                                            2711  64%
      - popup-create                                             2710  63%
         end-of-visual-line                                       245   5%
         beginning-of-visual-line                                 243   5%
         popup-vertical-motion                                    148   3%
       + posn-at-point                                             75   1%
         posn-col-row                                               2   0%
     + ac-remove-quick-help                                         1   0%
     + ac-update-candidates                                         1   0%
    + ac-start                                                      4   0%
   - ac-show-menu                                                1051  24%
    - ac-update                                                  1051  24%
     - ac-menu-create                                            1051  24%
      - popup-create                                             1051  24%
         end-of-visual-line                                        93   2%
         beginning-of-visual-line                                  92   2%
         popup-vertical-motion                                     53   1%
```

The value of `ac-sources` is: `(ac-source-nxml-tag ac-source-nxml-attr ac-source-nxml-attr-value ac-source-nxml-css ac-source-nxml-css-property ac-source-nxml-tag-value-by-nxml ac-source-nxml-tag-value-by-myself)`.

I tried changing it:

```el
(setq ac-sources '(ac-source-symbols ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers))
```

... and that has improved the performance a lot!

I also removed the `auto-complete-nxml` package and everything is working fine.

I'll try to find out more about `auto-complete-nxml`, because that has been working fine for months; I don't know what's gone wrong there.

Anyway, my problem is fixed. Many thanks everybody.

Comment: I think it's good if you set your answer as the accepted answer, so the question isn't registered as unanswered.

Comment: thanks, i will mark it as answered. after a long time searching help and trying 3 different browsers, i have discovered that i have to wait 48 hours before i can accept my own answer. my apologies for the noise. jack